# Blank field error while it has value in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

When I try to save my variable called `$data`, I get the following error(printed using var_dump):

```
array(2) {
  ["start_date"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "This field cannot be left blank"
  }
  ["end_date"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "This field cannot be left blank"
  }
}
```

But here is my `$data`(also printed using var_dump):

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "ASDF"
  ["start_date"]=>
  string(11) "1393/007/25"
  ["end_date"]=>
  string(11) "1393/007/28"
  ["category"]=>
  string(3) "ADF"
  ["awards"]=>
  string(4) "DASF"
}
```

(I have some validation rules in my model)

What am I doing wrong?!

**Update:**
Here are my validation rules:

```
var $validate = array(
        'name'=>'notEmpty',
        'start_date'=>array(
            'rule'=>'/^([1]{1})([0-9]{3})([\/]{1})([0-9]{2})([\/]{1})[0-9]{2}$/'
        ),
        'end_date'=>array(
            'rule'=>'/^([1]{1})([0-9]{3})([\/]{1})([0-9]{2})([\/]{1})[0-9]{2}$/'
        ),
    );
```

Comment: There may be an error in your date validation , please show us your validation rules , if not how can we give an answer , i can not read your mind ;)

Comment: I added them to the post. Any Ideas? @KanishkaPanamaldeniya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your date , in the month portion you have 3 digits

Change `[0-9]{2}` to `[0-9]{3}`

Your final regular expression should be changed from

```
'rule'=>'/^([1]{1})([0-9]{3})([\/]{1})([0-9]{2})([\/]{1})[0-9]{2}$/'
```

to

```
'rule'=>'/^[1]{1}[0-9]{3}[\/]{1}[0-9]{3}[\/]{1}[0-9]{2}$/'
```

Anyway why are you passing 3 digits to the month ?

Comment: My mistake... sry :))